# Making a Div slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have been at this for a good few hours, but I cant get it to work. Basically what im trying to do is have a featured box on my wordpress site, of 3 Divs that should automatically swap to one another after a few seconds, but many of the js solutions I've been trying havent worked.

Anyone have any ideas ?

The site can be found [here](http://staff.rokett.net/wordpress/)

Comment: Why haven't preready jquery solutions worked? There are a [million](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+slider) of them, especially [on google](http://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=jquery%20slider%20plugin&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=8cc02ffd2cbbb9ed&ix=seb&ion=1&ix=seb&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=8cc02ffd2cbbb9ed&biw=1366&bih=643&ix=seb&ion=1)

Comment: You also have a `404` for the `bootstrap-dropdown.js` and then jquery isn't defined and you're using it somewhere so you get an `Uncaught ReferenceError for $`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a quick example of how it could look like:

http://jsfiddle.net/5JW33/

```
function play() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var $visible = $('#featuredcontent>div:visible').fadeOut(1000);
        var $next = $visible.next();
        ($next.length ? $next : $('#featuredcontent>div:first-child')).fadeIn(1000, play);
    }, 5000);
}

play();​
```

Comment: Applied that, it removed the 2nd and 3rd boxes, but it doesnt hide and reveal them.

Comment: @AlexMcGill you have to wrap it in the jquery .ready() function: `$(function(){ /* ... here ... */ });`

Comment: AH ! Got it to work, All i need to do now is prevent the content slipping under it.

Comment: @AlexMcGill easiest way is to just set the `#featuredcontent` to a fixed height in css